# Dax code to calculate a new column by latest date, category and location

Tags: powerbi, dax

I wonder if anyone can help. I am trying to create a map and use conditional formatting and whilst I have a measure that can work out the below I am struggling to make it into a calculated column.
I have a range of data from some audits which includes scores and questions by category for various locations. I want to pull an overall  category sccore per location but just for the latest date and create a new table that shows this data.

So my data is as below and i want to know

combined score for the safety category for town a on the last date it was checked so for town a the answer would be 4.

| location | category | score | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| town a | safety | 2 | 1/2/24 |
| town a | safety | 2 | 1/2/24 |
| town a | safety | 1 | 30/3/23 |
| town a | data | 4 | 1/2/24 |
| town b | safety | 3 | 30/3/23 |
| town b | safety | 1 | 1/2/24 |

the reason for not doing it as a measure is that you cant use a measure as conditional formatting on a map

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for creating an intermediary table to determine the latest date for each location and category :

```
LatestCategoryDate = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'YourDataTable',
    'YourDataTable'[location],
    'YourDataTable'[category],
    "LatestDate", MAX('YourDataTable'[date])
)
```

[image]

Then add a calculated column to mark the rows that match the latest date for their respective location and category :

```
IsLatestDate = 
VAR CurrentDate = 'YourDataTable'[date]
VAR CurrentLocation = 'YourDataTable'[location]
VAR CurrentCategory = 'YourDataTable'[category]
RETURN
IF(
    CurrentDate = CALCULATE(MAX('YourDataTable'[date]), FILTER(ALL('YourDataTable'), 'YourDataTable'[location] = CurrentLocation && 'YourDataTable'[category] = CurrentCategory)),
    1,
    0
)
```

[image]

And you will be able to create a new table that only includes rows for the latest dates and then sum up scores for those rows.

```
AggregatedScores = 
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER('YourDataTable', 'YourDataTable'[IsLatestDate] = 1),
    'YourDataTable'[location],
    'YourDataTable'[category],
    "CombinedScore", SUM('YourDataTable'[score])
)
```